# How do I indicate the log level of a line of output from a systemd service?

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

I have a script that I intend to run as a systemd service.

I know that stdout and stderr will be routed to the systemd journal. Is there any way for me to indicate that a line of output be treated as INFO or ERROR or whatever is appropriate?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [systemd for Developers III: Revenge of the systemd](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/journal-submit.html) we find:

> The printed string in this example is logged at a default log priority
>   of LOG_INFO[1](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/journal-submit.html). Sometimes it is useful to change the log priority for
>   such a printed string. When systemd parses STDOUT/STDERR of a service
>   it will look for priority values enclosed in < > at the beginning of
>   each line

And the magic numbers are apparently copied from `syslog(3)` so

```
$ egrep 'INFO|ERR' /usr/include/sys/syslog.h | fgrep define
#define LOG_ERR     3   /* error conditions */
#define LOG_INFO    6   /* informational */
#define LOG_PERROR  0x20    /* log to stderr as well */
```

To emit info or error messages from e.g. a TCL script would look something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
puts "<3>auuugh"
puts "<6>infos"
```